# How can using a DNS server influence where I am perceived to be located

Tags: proxy, dns, ip-address, vpn

This blog post [("How to Easily Watch Netflix and Hulu From Anywhere in the World")](http://www.howtogeek.com/117528/how-to-easily-watch-netflix-and-hulu-from-anywhere-in-the-world/) explains how someone outside the US can watch Netflix and Hulu - which are typically restricted to people living inside the United States - by changing their DNS servers.

My question is, how can this change how Hulu sees your location?
From what I understand, a DNS server simply translates a web address into an IP address for you. However, at the end of the day, it's still **your** computer connecting to the website, let's say Hulu. Hulu still knows that my computer is not in the US. Hulu doesn't know how I got it's address (i.e. they don't care which DNS server told me)

*Instructions (reproduced from HowToGeek)*

> - Press the Win + R keyboard combination, then type ncpa.cpl into the run box and hit enter.
> - Then right-click on your current network adapter and choose properties from the context menu.
> - When the properties dialog opens, scroll down and choose Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4), then click the properties button.
> - Then change your DNS Settings to the following IP’s:
>
>   Preferred DNS: 149.154.158.186
>     Alternate DNS: 199.167.30.144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you have to know here is that these are [tunlr](https://tunlr.com/) DNS service IPs. The trick here is to route all the trafic through tunlr which enables you to use virtual locations instead of more traditional VPNs or proxies.

From their FAQ :

> Tunlr does not provide a virtual private network (VPN). Tunlr is a DNS (domain name system) unblocking service. We’re using sophisticated technologies (a.k.a. the Tunlr Secret Sauce ©) to re-adress certain data envelopes, tricking the receiver into thinking the envelope originated from within the U.S. For these data envelopes, Tunlr is transparently creating a network tunnel from your location to our U.S.-based servers. Any data that’s not directly related to the video or music content providers which Tunlr supports is not only left untouched, it’s also not even routed through Tunlr. In order to use Tunlr, you will have to change the DNS address. See Get started for more information.

For more information, you can refer either to the [FAQ/How it works section](https://tunlr.com/faq) or to [this discussion on SuperUser.](https://superuser.com/questions/461316/how-does-tunlr-work)

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. However this seems strange.  Why not just set up a webpage with a browser bar so you can surf the web through their site?

Comment: If they did that then **all** the stream will be proxied, which is of course too heavy for servers and introduces some lag on your side. By doing that, they can bypass only the initial geographic location check.